# tkinter background not showing

Tags: python, tkinter

I made new method called `start()` and pasted my `mainloop()` there, but it's not showing a picture anymore. How to fix it?

```
class Beerpong():
   def __init__(self):
      self.__main = Tk()
      self.__main.title("Beerpong made by: x")

      #Making background for game
      bg_image = PhotoImage(file="beerpong_table.gif")
      bg = Label(self.__main,image=bg_image)
      bg.pack()

   def start(self):
      self.__main.mainloop()


def main():
     ui = Beerpong()
     ui.start()

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `PhotoImage` created in the `__init__()` method is getting destroyed when it returns because it's stored in a the local variable `bg_image` (and local variables disappear when a function exits).

Here's some [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) I found that describes this (search for the "`# keep a reference!`" comment in the example code):

So here's how to apply the recommend way to to your own code (by making it an attribute of something that will still exist after the method returns):

```
from tkinter import *

class Beerpong():
   def __init__(self):
      self.__main = Tk()
      self.__main.title("Beerpong made by: x")

      #Making background for game
      bg_image = PhotoImage(file="beerpong_table.gif")
      bg = Label(self.__main,image=bg_image)
      bg.image = bg_image  # Save a reference to the PhotoImage.
      bg.pack()

   def start(self):
      self.__main.mainloop()


def main():
     ui = Beerpong()
     ui.start()

main()
```